# Sync left pane in Windows 7 Explorer with the opened folder

Tags: windows-7, sync, windows-explorer

When using the explorer in vista (and xp) if I drill into a folder in right pane of explorer, the folder view stays synchronised. However in Windows-7 I cannot see a simple way of forcing it to do the same.

Anyone have any ideas please?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Under the "Folder and Search Options" accessible from the "Organize" menu, there is an option to "Automatically expand to current folder".  I believe this is the setting you are looking for.

Comment: you're both right - but I'll accept yours as you rep is much lower.

Comment: NB: Works only if the folder is a visible (unhidden) part of the tree, try `C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData`

Answer (score 16):

I found this option on Windows 7 Professional (just right click on an empty space on the left pane):

[image: Windows Explorer]

[Thanks to [vkapartzianis](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/profile/c52a0e09-589a-4052-904d-e53d395a305f)]

Comment: Nice one mate!!

Answer (score 10):

Folder Options > General > Navigation pane

check the box **Automatically expand to current folder**

Answer (score 4):

And in case anybody is curious about how to do it for Windows 10, go to the View tab, go to Options, select "Expand..." and go to "View" tab and you'll find the options at the very bottom (Navigation Pane).

Comment: That option is checked in my instance, but I still had to do the "click in empty space" in the left and select "Expand to Current Folder".  I remembered this option but, in case it helps someone, empty space is not to the left or right of a folder name. Folders span the window width for the purposes of this activity so you'll need to be above or below them.